# compiling QT 4,8,0 in windows 7 x64 with visual studio 2010 gives makefile not found

Tags: qt, nmake

i have a problem.. i'm trying to compile qt for vs 2010..
But i can't..
i'm following this guide:
http://thomasstockx.blogspot.com/2011/03/qt-472-in-visual-studio-2010.html

i follow all the steps (with the exception of -shared config, because i want -static) but when i digit nmake the vs prompt tell me this:

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility versione 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Tutti i diritti riservati.

NMAKE : fatal error U1064: MAKEFILE non trovato. Nessuna destinazione specificat
a.
Stop.

c:\Qt\4.8.0>
```

it didn't find the makefile... i try with 2 different pcs with the same version of qt, vs and windows and in both don't work so i do something wrong.. but i can't understand where..i triedsearching but with no luck...
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you sure configure.exe succeeded? Check for errors in its output.

Comment: Also, Qt 4.8 is not released at the time of this post (it's only in RC). If you don't have a specific reason to use it (and compile it yourself), you would be better off with using the binary packages for 4.7. I suggest installing it via the SDK manager, that way you can upgrade later (but you can also install the 4.8RC if you want).

Comment: @Tamás Szelei Qt 4.8.0 was released on Dec 15th. There's VS 2010 packages though, so I'd suggest to try those.

Comment: I can't try that because i need to run a project that requires static libraries... configure.exe suxceed... the only warning is about perl missing

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely install Perl and try again. If it's not needed why should it give that message at all?
However, I don't seem to remember I had Perl installed so the error is rather strange.
The tutorial was written originally for Qt 4.7.2 and worked up to 4.7.4.
But I haven't tested it with 4.8. Before 4.8, VS2010 just wasn't supported by Qt, this has recently changed, so like Frank said, you should probably try to download the VS2010 packages since they now support it.

Comment: And like i already said i need static libraries... The packages you can download for vs2010 are shared... I need to complile them.. About perl it was a warning... I try installing perl but the result is the same... Maybe it don't work compiling on a x64 os...