# Building 64-bit Qt on Windows 7? (Qt 5.0.2, MS Visual Studio 2012)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-7, qt5

[If posting this as a separate question is inappropriate: I tried to append this as a "sub question" to the relevant answer for the original question. However, I could not find out how to do this so I opted for posting it as a fresh question. When I have resolved this question though, I intend to append the answer to the appropriate section of the link in the following paragraph.]

I'm trying to get Qt to work with visual studio 2012 on a Windows 7 professional 64-bit PC. I found some very useful instructions in one of the answers for the question posed at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16533188/2903608

I am failing at the very last hurdle though, point number 14. When I type in the nmake command:

> nmake /I /K

I get this fatal error:

> C:\Qt\qt>nmake /I /K /A
>
> Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 11.00.50727.1
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> NMAKE : fatal error U1064: MAKEFILE not found and no target specified
>   Stop.
>
> C:\Qt\qt>

I have been trying to use Google and Stack Overflow to research a solution to my problem but I'm not having much luck.

The closest specific information on the U1064 fatal error that I can find is here:
[compiling QT 4,8,0 in windows 7 x64 with visual studio 2010 gives makefile not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8823786/2903608)
It describes checking whether Perl was successfully installed (I got the latest version of ActivePerl) and looking for error messages in the output of configure.exe. This morning I have attempted steps 5 through 14 once more but the outcome is the same and I cannot find any apparent errors in the process to assist me in debugging the problem.

Following the blogspot link (http://thomasstockx.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/qt-472-in-visual-studio-2010.html) of the above Stack Overflow question ([compiling QT 4,8,0 in windows 7 x64 with visual studio 2010 gives makefile not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8823786/2903608)) suggested that I should include the platform argument when using the configure command which was described in point 12. So I included the argument:

> -platform win32-msvc2012

The same information can be found at Qt: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/install-win.html. According to that page, if I need to reconfigure and rebuild Qt all I need to do is type "nmake distclean". But if I do that I get another fatal error:

> C:\Qt\qt>nmake distclean
>
> Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 11.00.50727.1
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'distclean' Stop.
>
> C:\Qt\qt>

So in summary, I think something substantial is missing since nmake cannot find the makefile in the instance of the first fatal error. I'm assuming the makefile should have been produced by the configure action of point 12 but I cannot find any hint there. I am attaching the log files that I have created to capture the output of points 11 and 12 in case I missed anything there.

Actually, there are two lines at the end of configure.exe that mentioned "Unknown part .." But I am assuming that these refer to modules that are not critical here:

> ```
> [..]
> Unknown part demos passed to -nomake.
> Unknown part webkit passed to -nomake.
>
> C:\Qt\qt
> ```

---

List of software (versions)

- Git-1.8.4-preview20130916.exe
- ActivePerl-5.16.3.1603-MSWin32-x64-296746.msi
- rubyinstaller-1.9.3-p448.exe

---

### 23/10/2013: EDIT

Apologies, it is not possible to attach files to this website. However, it is possible to use websites such as pastebin.com.

Output from configure.exe:
http://pastebin.com/CzHTcJE3

Output from Perl:
http://pastebin.com/Hf6hgiwU

As far as I can tell, I can't see any problems reported by configure.exe.

Comment: Did you get any errors when you ran configure? That part is supposed to create the makefile.

Comment: There were no errors reported by configure. However,I was able to get around the problem by using the installer directly from the Qt  website and successful installed Qt.

Comment: I see two warnings: "Unknown part demos passed to -nomake.
Unknown part webkit passed to -nomake." I would get these out of the configure line. And try again.

Comment: I could be wrong but in the instructions I followed, it said that the WebKit module has issues and should not be included. So I would assume that the instructions that I followed would omit WebKit. In any case, I tried solving this problem by using the relevant installer directly off Qt's website and I am now able to build Qt projects in MSVS 2012. So for me, trying to build Qt from source was unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether this is the correct procedure regarding answering my own question. However, I was able to resolve my issues by avoiding building from source and instead downloaded an official installer from Qt's website: http://qt-project.org/downloads

So if anyone stumbles upon this question in the future and really needs to build from source, I'm afraid I'm only able to refer that person back to the original question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16533188/2903608